# Case sensitive Cmd+D in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

In ST2 <kbd>⌘+D</kbd> expands the selection to the next word, using case insensitive matching. Is it possible to match the word case sensitive?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

If you select `Case sensitive` in `Find` dialog (<kbd>⌘+F</kbd>), it will be remembered for <kbd>⌘+D</kbd> as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the "case sensitive" behavior on the fly? i.e. If you've already selected the word and are ready to hit CTRL+D, can you toggle between case-sensitive & case-insensitive states without opening up the find dialog?

Comment: The default shortcut to toggle case sensitiveness is CMD+Alt+C (ALT+C on Linux and Windows). But I think it only works with Find dialog opened... Anyway, you can open the Find dialog with CMD+F and hit CMD+ALT+C before your next CMD+D.

Comment: This has bothered me for ages and I had checked through the preferences with a fine tooth comb to no avail. Thank you!