# How to select all instances of a variable and edit variable name in Sublime

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, key-bindings

If I select a *variable* (not just any string) in my code, all other instances of that variable get a stroke (white outline) around them:

[image]

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will let me **select all of those instances of the variable and edit them all at once?**

---

### Things I've Tried:

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> lets me select them one-by-one, but I have to manually exclude the non-variable string matches:

[image]

And using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> simply selects *all* the string matches:

[image]

Clearly, Sublime is able to differentiate between variable and string matches. Is there no way to select just the variable matches?

Answer (score 655, accepted):

1. Put the cursor in the variable.

   *Note:* the key is to start with an empty selection. Don't highlight; just *put* your cursor there.

[image: text cursor on variable]

2. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> as needed. Not on a Mac? Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

[image: more instances of variable highlighted]

Didn't work? Try again, making sure to *start with nothing selected*.

More commands:

> *Find All:* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> selects all occurences at once. Not on a Mac? <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>
>
> *Undo Selection:* <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> steps backwards. Not on a Mac? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>
>
> *Quick Skip Next:* <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> skips the next occurence. Not on a Mac? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
>
> [Sublime Docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html)

Comment: For case-sensitive searching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829336/case-sensitive-cmdd-in-sublime-text-2

Comment: how do you do this with ubuntu?

Comment: What is ⌘, how do you do this on a non-MAC keyboard?

Comment: at least in ST3 you can do Ctrl-⌘-G without the other ⌘-D command. Its terribly mislabeled in the menu unfortunately!

Comment: @BjarkeFreund-Hansen see elaRosca's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19913390/483520

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's original question. He specifically asked `variable (not just any string)`. This simply selects all occurrences of the string.

Comment: @BetjaminRichards Make sure you're not selecting (highlighting) the variable. Just move the cursor onto the variable and then press ⌘D. Incidentally, this is exactly the issue I had with MattDMo's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16844924/483520).

Comment: It's startlingly simple but not intuitive at all since I've tried everything except this. This helps soooo much, thanks!

Comment: Does it find all instance of that variable or anything that matches that word. Because later is way less useful in some cases.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Anything that matches the word, taking boundaries into account. Not a true variable search, but much better than simple string matching.

Comment: i found sublime plugin, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9K7mxWItPw, it allows you to rename instances of var/functions.Not just every word

Comment: I am using ST3 and Windows. Your second example is what I was searching for, but the equivalent command,'Alt+F3', giving to replace yours 'Ctrl⌘G', is not running like the example, because it select all string ocurrences, not just instances, like it should do. Any idea of what is happen?

Comment: @Nolan, your mention to Betjamin ends one of my growing frustration.

Comment: You can set up your own hotkey for it. The command is `find_all_under`. E.g.: Go to Preferences -> Key bindings, insert `{ "keys": ["alt+d"], "command": "find_all_under" },`

Comment: @Doglas In Sublime Text 3, don't `Ctrl` `D`, simply `Alt` `F3`.

Comment: VScode has `F2` hotkey that renames all instances in all files that import the variable / class. Extremely useful. Same is possible with `Ctrl + T, Ctrl + M` after installing typescript package. At the bottom of the screen an input where the name can be edited is presented. This is a far more superior solution than `Alt + F3`, which is constrained to the local file.

Answer (score 139):

I know the question is about Macs, but I got here searching the answer for Ubuntu, so I guess my answer could be useful to someone.

Easy way to do it: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: its still selecting everything which has foo inside.

Comment: This answer is for the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12162047/2270563. But here the question is different. To select only the variables rather than all matches.

Comment: @user1767754 If you don't want to select all that has `foo` inside, don't already select the first `foo`. Instead just place a cursor in the word `foo` and then `Alt-F3`. Voila

Comment: This answer is wrong. This will select all instance of `foo` not just the highlighted ones.

Comment: Doesn't work in KDE, so I just added { "keys": ["alt+d"], "command": "find_all_under" } to the key bindings file: Preferences > Key BIndings. alt+d doesn't seem to conflict with anything there.

Answer (score 53):

Despite much effort, I have not found a built-in or plugin-assisted way to do what you're trying to do. I completely agree that it *should* be possible, as the program can distinguish `foo` from `buffoon` when you first highlight it, but no one seems to know a way of doing it.

---

However, here are some useful key combos for selecting words in Sublime Text 2:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> - selects all occurrences of the current word (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> on Windows/Linux)

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> - selects the next instance of the current word (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)

- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> - skips the current instance and goes on to select the next one (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> - "soft undo", moves back to the previous selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>)

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> - uses the current selection as the "Find" field in Find and Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)

Comment: But the stroke appears only around occurrences of the *variable name*,  while `⌘+D` acts on all occurrences of the string. For example, if I highlight `foo`, sublime wonderfully strokes all the variable `foo`s, but not the string `foo` in my `eject_buffoon` function. And yet using the key combos above, I'm forced to manually `⌘+K` out the string matches to avoid having an `eject_bufbarn` function. There must be a better way!

Comment: @Nolan - feel free to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and see if anyone has any suggestions. One possible workaround is to select `foo_` (foo and the space after it) or `_foo_` (spaces both before and after) and then use `⌘-D` or `Ctrl-⌘-D`.

Comment: I actually think this is exactly the question that the OP was asking. He specifically says "*variable*" (not "text region" or "string") and "*stroke*" (not "highlighting"). And this question is *not* a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162047/sublime-text-editor-how-to-select-all-instances-of-selected-region - that one says "highlighted selection". Also, of course, `foo` often shows up as `(foo)`, `_foo,`, `(foo,`, and `_foo}`, so `_foo_` is pretty unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 21):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11549737/623735) worked for me. Put your cursor at the beginning of the word you want to replace, then

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> ...

That should select as many instances of the word as you like, then you can just type the replacement.

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me apart for the answer that have been mentioned. Good !

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @MD004 How so ?

Comment: @hobs The question is how to "select all of those instances" *at once*. I'll admit the phrasing of the question in the title is ambiguous, but later in the post the OP describes your solution and says that this "selects them one-by-one, but I have to manually exclude the non-variable string matches" which is unsatisfactory. Btw, an example scenario where this is unsatisfactory is when there are, say, 1000 occurrences of the word you want to replace, in which case manually selecting them is not an option.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you. Now I see why the accepted answer is much better for the OP's situation and your 1000-occurence example.

Answer (score 13):

The Magic is, you have to start with an empty selection, so put your cursor in front of the word/character you want to multi-select and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> .

Comment: This is the answer for variables of single characters. For any other variables, you can put the cursor anywhere in the variable to start with.

Comment: This works for me in Sublime 3 and is the simplest way to do it if you want to limit the changes to a smaller area like within a function as opposed to the whole file. Command-D for macOS, of course.

Answer (score 10):

To me, this is the biggest mistake in Sublime. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> is hard to reach/remember, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> makes no sense considering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is "add next instance to selection".

Add this to your [User Key Bindings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html) (Preferences > Key Bindings):

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+d"], "command": "find_all_under" },
```

Now you can highlight something, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and it will add every other instance in the file to the selection.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the original question!

Comment: Still selects strings and comments

Comment: Ctrl-Shit-D is a rather standard shortcut for 'duplicate selection' though

Answer (score 6):

As user1767754 said, the key here is to not make any selection initially.

Just place the cursor inside the variable name, don't double click to select it. For single character variables, place the cursor at the front or end of the variable to not make any selection initially.

Now keep hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for next variable selection or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for selecting all variables at once. It will magically select only the variables.

Answer (score 5):

It's [mentioned by @watsonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844657/how-to-select-all-instances-of-a-variable-and-edit-variable-name-in-sublime-text#comment37075817_18422707) that in Sublime Text 3 on macOS, starting with an *empty selection*, simply <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> on Windows) does the trick, instead of <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> in Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, 2020-10-17, if you select a text element and hit CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+M it will highlight every instance within the code chunk.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case anyone else stumbled on this question while looking for a way to replace a string across multiple files, it is <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>