# How can I switch a PHP variable in Sublime Text 2 under Vintage mode?

Tags: php, vim, sublimetext2

I'd like press 'yiw' to copy inner word.  It's currently right copy a PHP variable include prefix "$" in my vim configuration.  But it don't include prefix "$" in my sublime text 2 vintage mode.

How can i do to let it work currently? And I also don't know how to set this in vim.

Comment: In Vim, see `:help iskeyword`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime, open `Preferences -> Settings - User` and add the following line to it:

```json
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

This is the same line taken from the `Preferences -> Settings - Default` file, only the `$` has been removed. While in INSERT MODE, you can now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on OSX) to select the full variable name, including `$`, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) to copy. For more useful keyboard shortcuts for selecting words, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844924/1426065) of mine.

Comment: Thank you very much. And thanks for you can read my English ;)