# Could Sublime text 3 on Windows find next variable with same name smart?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Windows 8 x64, Sublime Text 3.

Here it is, I want to select all the variable with the same name in the file.

If I choose one of them, the one will be highlighted, all the others will be circled automatically, it's seems like Sublime text could recognize who is the word may be I want, even if they have the same word.

for example, if I choose `num`, ST will circle the word `num` but skip the word like `num2` etc.

but neither I using `ctrl+d` or `alt+f3`, I couldn't just choose these variables safety - if there was other same word but not variable name in the code file. I just can't skip it. the `num` in `num2` will also be highlighted.

Is there any way to choose the variables clean and safety like it been circled?  or better, just choose the variables?

Comment: you should keep in the mind - Sublime Text is an Editor, not IDE. You could achive what you want using [plugins](https://packagecontrol.io/) but quality of that plugins could be different :)

Answer (score 1):

After asking myself the same question and searching lots and lots, I found the answer [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11574#p45552) on the official forum and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422707/3460805) on SO (discarding results for ST2 wasn't that good of an idea after all ...)

1. Place your cursor on the word, ***without selecting it***.
2. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Or ...

1. Select the word,
2. In the `Find` menu, select `Find...` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>),
3. Tick the `Whole word` option (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>),
4. Press the `Find All` button (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you very much! It's seems not to find variables but the word in special format. When I'm searching simple variable name like 'n', the 'n' in statement “printf("%d\n", var);" was been highlighted too. Anyway, It's much better than ctrl-d : )