# Sublime Text: select/edit all occurrences of variable *scoped to function*

Tags: sublimetext3

Sublime provides ability to:

- select/edit all occurrences of a variable (Quick Find All; alt+F3 on Windows)
- select each occurrence one-by-one and then edit the summed total (Quick Add Next; ctrl+d on Windows)

What I want:

- select/edit all occurrences **within a function's scope**

note: I've read this related link ([Sublime Text: Select all instances of a variable and edit variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844657/sublime-text-select-all-instances-of-a-variable-and-edit-variable-name)) and didn't see an answer to how editing might be restricted to function scope.

Comment: which language syntax (highlighting) are you using? depending on the answer, there may be a way to write a small plugin to do this

Comment: @KeithHall Cheers, Keith; I'm using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a fairly simple plugin to do this, making use of Quick Find All, and then just removing any selections that are not inside the current function.

- From the Tools menu -> Developer -> New Plugin...
- Replace the contents of the new tab with the following:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class SelectWordInFunctionCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        prev_sel = [sel for sel in view.sel()]
        function_region = next((region for region in view.find_by_selector('meta.function') if region.contains(view.sel()[0])), None)
        if function_region:
            #word = view.expand_by_class(view.sel()[0].begin(), sublime.CLASS_WORD_START + sublime.CLASS_WORD_END)
            view.window().run_command('find_all_under')
            sel = [sel for sel in view.sel() if function_region.contains(sel)]
            view.sel().clear()
            view.sel().add_all(sel if any(sel) else prev_sel)
        else:
            view.window().status_message('Not inside a function')
```

- instead of using the `find_all_under` command, use `select_word_in_function` - you can create a keybinding to do this only when inside a function definition:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+f3"], "command": "select_word_in_function", "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "meta.function", "match_all": true },
    ]
},
```

Disclaimer: this definitely works with PHP in ST build 3142 and other syntaxes that scope the whole function, but a different approach to detect where the function starts and ends may need to be used for other syntaxes that can't/don't behave this way.