# How to select occurrences that respect Find panel's flags in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Currently, pressing `CMD+D` is selecting partial matches, regardless of Find panel's "whole word" or "case sensitive" toggles.

Example:

```
job.findJob('something');
job.done();
```

If I select `job` and press `CMD+D` with the Find panel visible and "whole word" and "case sensitive" enabled, unfortunately the `Job` in `findJob` gets added to my selection.

How can I instruct Sublime Text to respect the Find panel's flags?

Comment: Don't select the text `job` first; just put the cursor on it and press the key. If you select text, Sublime infers that you want to select all variations of the text. If you start out with nothing selected, you're telling it you want to select other like things.

Comment: @OdatNurd you're a wizard Harry.... that's actually the answer, can't believe it, thank you

Comment: In regards to the problem, Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text: Select all instances of a variable and edit variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844657/sublime-text-select-all-instances-of-a-variable-and-edit-variable-name), 
though Find panel's flags are mentioned in the title which is not supported.